# Eclipse "Clean Project" not working

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Following Lynda's C++ Essential Training, I've come across something that looks really simple but somehow I can't fix (regarding Eclipse, not C++):

*Clean Project won't delete the files it's supposed to when I use it.*

This is the practice adopted by Bill Weinman on the training, and I know it's not a big deal, but it bugs the heck out of me that it just isn't working.

Running Kepler on Windows 8 with latest CDT tools (just installed!).

Thanks.

EDIT: Thought I'd add the console output for the clean attempts:

```
18:51:35 **** Clean-only build of configuration Debug for project WCopy ****
rm -rf 

18:51:35 Build Finished (took 74ms)
```

Comment: Be sure to uncheck "Automatically Rebuild Project"

Comment: That wasn't it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The clean is working but not in the way that Weinman shows. Test by doing this:

1. Add x.cpp file file to the working project and run it;
2. Add y.cpp file file to the working project and run it;
3. Delete x.cpp from working project and run it and run y.cpp; --> It will fail
4. Run "clean" on the project;
5. Run y.cpp again; --> It will be ok;